# Jupyter Lab Remote Tunnel Link

Tags: python, jupyter, cluster-computing, slurm, ssh-tunnel

Is there a way to launch a Jupyter Lab server that is accessible through a direct tunnel link (NOT via SSH) in a similar way that is available in [VSCode Remote Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels)?
The use case is when running the server over a randomly assigned compute node in a cluster; In the standard way one has to run the server, then run an ssh tunnel command on the local host to map to that compute node through the main login node of the cluster.

My goal is to obviate this tunneling command step on the local host.